# facebook redirect_uri not accepted

Tags: macos, cocoa, facebook-graph-api, swift2

I set the redirect_uri in settings>advanced on my app dashboard and my code seems to be correct, however i still got the message :
the parameter redirect_uri is required.

I thought this was an issue of non espaced characters but escaping the url does not change anything.

```
    let webView = WebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 600))
    let string = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={ap_id}&amp;redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html/"
    // escape unwanted characters
    if let urlwithPercentEscapes = string.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()) {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlwithPercentEscapes)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
        print(request)
    }
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested this was due to a bogue in Facebook documentation, every character was escaped so `&` became `&amp;`

Replacing every occurence of `&amp;` by `&` solved the issue.
Bogue reported and fixed.